# Spring MVC webapp HTTP Status 400

Tags: spring, http

Im developing a webapp with Spring and hibernate. I have a simple form with a text field and a select:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf8" pageEncoding="utf8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English"/>
    <!--    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<c:url value="/resources/site.css"/>">
    <title>Nuevo expediente</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Nuevo expediente</h2>
    <form:form modelAttribute="expediente" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Tipo de expediente:</td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="tipoExpediente">
                <form:option value="-" label="Seleccione un tipo"/>
                <form:options items="${expedientes}" itemValue="tipoExpediente" itemLabel="tipoExpediente" />
            </form:select>
            <form:errors path="tipoExpediente" element="span"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Estado:</td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="estado"/>
            <form:errors path="estado" element="span"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form show correctly, but when i submit, I get a HTTP Status 400 exception, with the description:

```
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()..
```

I have read that it would be caused by requestparams, but i not using them.

Here is my controller:

```
package com.atlantis.atecliente.controller;

import com.atlantis.atecliente.model.Book;
import com.atlantis.atecliente.model.Expediente;
import com.atlantis.atecliente.model.TipoExpediente;
import com.atlantis.atecliente.repository.ExpedienteService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ExpedienteController {

@Autowired
protected ExpedienteService service;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/*", "/expedientes"})
public String getExpedientes(Model model) {
    List<Expediente> expedientes = service.getExpedientes();
    model.addAttribute("expedientes", expedientes);
    return "expediente";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "nuevo-expediente")
public String createExpedienteGet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("expediente", new Expediente());
    List<TipoExpediente> tiposExpediente = service.getTiposExpedientes();
//        List<String> canales = service.getCanales();
    model.addAttribute("expedientes", tiposExpediente);
//        model.addAttribute("canales", canales);
    return "nuevo-expediente";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "nuevo-expediente", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createExpedientePost(@ModelAttribute("expediente") Expediente expediente)     {
    service.createExpediente(expediente);
    return "redirect:expedientes";
}
}
```

Finalyy the Expediente class:

```
package com.atlantis.atecliente.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Expediente")
public class Expediente {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int codExpediente;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoExpediente")
private TipoExpediente tipoExpediente;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estadoExpediente")
private EstadoExpediente estadoExpediente;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "expedientePadre")
private Expediente expedientePadre;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoRelacion")
private TipoRelacion tipoRelacion;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "canalEntrada")
private CanalExpediente canalEntrada;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idiomaEntrada")
private IdiomaExpediente idiomaEntrada;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idiomaSalida")
private IdiomaExpediente idiomaSalida;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoResolucion")
private TipoResolucion tipoResolucion;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "canalSalida")
private CanalExpediente canalSalida;

@Column(length = 30)
private String estado;

@Column(length = 10)
private String numeroSerie;

@Column(length = 10)
private String numeroHoja;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaRedaccion;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaRecepcion;

@Column(length = 200)
private String asunto;

@Column (length = 1000)
private String descripcion;

@Column(length = 20)
private String usuarioRegistro;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaRegistro;

@Column (length = 20)
private String usuarioModificacion;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaModificacion;

@Column (length = 20)
private String usuarioCierre;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaCierre;

public int getCodExpediente() {
    return codExpediente;
}

public void setCodExpediente(int codExpediente) {
    this.codExpediente = codExpediente;
}

public EstadoExpediente getEstadoExpediente() {
    return estadoExpediente;
}

public void setEstadoExpediente(EstadoExpediente estadoExpediente) {
    this.estadoExpediente = estadoExpediente;
}

public Expediente getExpedientePadre() {
    return expedientePadre;
}

public void setExpedientePadre(Expediente expedientePadre) {
    this.expedientePadre = expedientePadre;
}

public TipoRelacion getTipoRelacion() {
    return tipoRelacion;
}

public void setTipoRelacion(TipoRelacion tipoRelacion) {
    this.tipoRelacion = tipoRelacion;
}

public CanalExpediente getCanalEntrada() {
    return canalEntrada;
}

public void setCanalEntrada(CanalExpediente canalEntrada) {
    this.canalEntrada = canalEntrada;
}

public IdiomaExpediente getIdiomaEntrada() {
    return idiomaEntrada;
}

public void setIdiomaEntrada(IdiomaExpediente idiomaEntrada) {
    this.idiomaEntrada = idiomaEntrada;
}

public IdiomaExpediente getIdiomaSalida() {
    return idiomaSalida;
}

public void setIdiomaSalida(IdiomaExpediente idiomaSalida) {
    this.idiomaSalida = idiomaSalida;
}

public TipoResolucion getTipoResolucion() {
    return tipoResolucion;
}

public void setTipoResolucion(TipoResolucion tipoResolucion) {
    this.tipoResolucion = tipoResolucion;
}

public CanalExpediente getCanalSalida() {
    return canalSalida;
}

public void setCanalSalida(CanalExpediente canalSalida) {
    this.canalSalida = canalSalida;
}

public String getUsuarioRegistro() {
    return usuarioRegistro;
}

public void setUsuarioRegistro(String usuarioRegistro) {
    this.usuarioRegistro = usuarioRegistro;
}

public String getNumeroSerie() {
    return numeroSerie;
}

public void setNumeroSerie(String numeroSerie) {
    this.numeroSerie = numeroSerie;
}

public String getNumeroHoja() {
    return numeroHoja;
}

public void setNumeroHoja(String numeroHoja) {
    this.numeroHoja = numeroHoja;
}

public Date getFechaRedaccion() {
    return fechaRedaccion;
}

public void setFechaRedaccion(Date fechaRedaccion) {
    this.fechaRedaccion = fechaRedaccion;
}

public Date getFechaRecepcion() {
    return fechaRecepcion;
}

public void setFechaRecepcion(Date fechaRecepcion) {
    this.fechaRecepcion = fechaRecepcion;
}

public String getAsunto() {
    return asunto;
}

public void setAsunto(String asunto) {
    this.asunto = asunto;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public Date getFechaRegistro() {
    return fechaRegistro;
}

public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
    this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
}

public String getUsuarioModificacion() {
    return usuarioModificacion;
}

public void setUsuarioModificacion(String usuarioModificacion) {
    this.usuarioModificacion = usuarioModificacion;
}

public Date getFechaModificacion() {
    return fechaModificacion;
}

public void setFechaModificacion(Date fechaModificacion) {
    this.fechaModificacion = fechaModificacion;
}

public String getUsuarioCierre() {
    return usuarioCierre;
}

public void setUsuarioCierre(String usuarioCierre) {
    this.usuarioCierre = usuarioCierre;
}

public Date getFechaCierre() {
    return fechaCierre;
}

public void setFechaCierre(Date fechaCierre) {
    this.fechaCierre = fechaCierre;
}

public TipoExpediente getTipoExpediente() {
    return tipoExpediente;
}

public void setTipoExpediente(TipoExpediente tipoExpediente) {
    this.tipoExpediente = tipoExpediente;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
}
```

Some help?

Thanks

Comment: Show your post payload and `Expediente` class.

Comment: Expediente class added. Sorry, but what it is the post payload?

Comment: What was actually send to to server.

Comment: Also enable debug logging. This way you can get a clue about what's going wrong with your request. You might also want to post the relevant piece of log so other can look at it as well.

Comment: The problem is that when I debug de app, any message is logged... The only clue is that when I put a breakpoiing at the first line of the function public String createExpedienteGet(Model model), it never arrive... so the mapping is fail....

Comment: No it will never arrive at the method. Just log everything you can. Spring becomes very chatty when you set the logger to TRACE or DEBUG. If I don't have a clue where to look I just start logging the whole framework for one request and analyze that piece of output.

Comment: Im using netBeans, and when I debug, the console debug dont show anything. I only can show you the server log... I add it to the post

Comment: The log up the pos timit :s

Comment: A clue that i dont understand. When i am debuggin step by step the code, the cursor jump from line      <form:select path="tipoExpediente"> to the line         </td> . It is normal? only execute the <form:select> tag whole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolve this issue. The problem was with the controller method mapping to the url.

I modified the function *createExpedientePost* to:

```
public String createExpedientePost(@ModelAttribute("expediente") Expediente expediente, BindingResult result) {
```

The change was the addition of BindingResult as an argument.

I hope this may help others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems somebody can get such error status, when arguments for a controller method were set incorrectly.
For instance I had the same because of wrong name of referer header(It was called as referrer)

```
public String foo(@RequestHeader(value = "referer") final String referer) {}
```